# How to record 2 digits decimal value to SQL Server database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a SQL database; in one table I set a field to `decimal(8,1)` and I recorded several rows. But now, I want to keep recording as `decimal(18,2)` with two digits. I changed the field property from 8,1 to 18,2. But When I add a new row or update a row with 2 digits on the table I see the second digit is always 0 "zero".

I am using an ASP.NET web application in order to manage the database data.
Record command line for that field:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", Convert.ToDecimal(dcMiktar.Text));
```

For example I recorded 9,14 for that field; but I still see 9,10 in the database:

[image]

How can I fix that!

Edit: When I try to record 9,11 - 9,12 - 9,13 - 9,14: I see its recorded as 9,10 in database, when I try 9,15-9,16-9,17-9,18-9,19: I see its recorded as 9,20 in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've changed the type of the column in the database but it looks like you haven't changed the type of the parameter in line with it. Check that `@4` is of type decimal(18,2) in the stored procedure you are using. If you are using inline SQL then please provide the full client code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; but the recording or updating achieved not with stored procedure; its sql record and update command line with parameters.

Comment: Have you got access to SQL Profiler to check what SQL is being submitted? i.e. does the query pass two decimal places? Also how are you retrieving the results? Could the rounding to one place be happening at that point?

Comment: @goba, I suggest you avoid [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) and construct the parameter to match the actual SQL server column data type along with maximum precision and scale.

Comment: @strickt01 Your comment guided me to find a solution to the problem; I reliazed that there was a command line in text_changed attribute forcing the text input rounding the two decimal digits to one digit with text formatting. Many thanks. I have already fixed the problem.